# How to execute a particular command after clicking an extension's icon in VSCode's activity bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension and just finished adding the icon to the activity bar. What I want to do is, execute a command whenever the user clicks that icon. This is what I have tried:

Package.json

```
"viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "myID",
          "title": "Testing",
          "icon": "res/logo.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "myID": [
        {
          "id": "Explorer",
          "name": "Browse contents",
          "commands": "vscode-myorg.getContents"
        }
      ]
    }
```

However, the `vscode-myorg.getContents` command is not getting executed after clicking the icon. How can I achieve this?

Comment: there is no `vscode-workat.getProblems` command defined

Comment: @rioV8 I made a typo while writing the question. I have the command `vscode-myorg.getContents` defined and registered in the respective files

Comment: clicking the activity bar icon does not execute a command it shows the contained views. Add a view and in this view add menu commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at [Feature Request: Add an API event to indicate when the sidebar viewlet changes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38870) which was closed as waiting for another still open issue on `getContext` to be resolved.  And using intellisense in package.json there is no  other key besides `id`, `title` and `icon`.  So you cannot put a `command` entry there for instance (I tried and nothing happened.)

There are a couple of other options that might work for you:

If your views are populated by a `TreeView` then you can detect when that treeViews' `visibility` changes:

```js
myTree.onDidChangeVisibility(ev => {
    console.log(ev);                      // ev.visibiltiy = true/false
})
```

So you can detect when the view becomes visible because the Activity Bar icon is clicked.  That does work.  However, this event is also triggered when the view is already opened and the user just collapses or expands that individual view.  And I don't think there is really any way to distinguish between the two conditions.

If you are populating your views with a `WebView` there is also an `onDidChangeVisibility` event for that.

---

There is an activation event for a View becoming active:

```
"activationEvents": [
  "onView:package-dependencies"
]
```

but that will only fire the first time a view is activated - and starts your extension's `activate` function so is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this can work as a temporary workaround until the feature you linked gets resolved. I am using a WebView, so your solution will work for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to define any new command of yours.

```
 "commands": [

      {
        "command": "vscode-workat.getProblems",
        "title": "Get Problems"
      },
]
```

as well as register it in the extension.

Comment: Im sorry, I made a typo while writing the question. I have the command defined and registered in both `package.json` and `extension.js`. It doesn't work despite that